# latexmk reaches maximum runs when including new glossaries entries

Tags: glossaries, latexmk

I have a problem with latexmk and the glossaries package. I have a large `scrbook' document organised with a main file and several chapter files. In my preamble I have a large quantity of acronyms defined (around 30 I believe). The problem is that when I add \gls{} entries to the document and then typeset with latexmk (I use TexShop on Mac OSX), it reaches maximum number of runs and returns an error. I wasn't able to recreate the error with a minimal document to post here unfortunately, but I was hoping that somebody could give me a hint on where to look at least, for example with known package conflicts or something like that.
This is the last part of the log for the error:

```
Rule 'bibtex thesis': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'thesis.aux'
------------
Run number 2 of rule 'bibtex thesis'
------------
------------
Running 'bibtex  "thesis"'
------------
Latexmk: applying rule 'bibtex thesis'...
For rule 'bibtex thesis', running '&run_bibtex(  )' ...
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2015)
The top-level auxiliary file: thesis.aux
The style file: ieeetr.bst
Database file #1: thesis_references.bib
Warning--entry type for "goalwebsite" isn't style-file defined
--line 324 of file thesis_references.bib
(There was 1 warning)
Rule 'cusdep acr acn thesis': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'thesis.acr'
------------
Run number 3 of rule 'cusdep acr acn thesis'
------------
Latexmk: applying rule 'cusdep acr acn thesis'...
For rule 'cusdep acr acn thesis', running '&do_cusdep( makeacr2acn )' ...
This is makeindex, version 2.15 [TeX Live 2015] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning style file ./thesis.ist.............................done (29 attributes redefined, 0 ignored).
Scanning input file thesis.acr...done (0 entries accepted, 72 rejected).
Nothing written in thesis.acn.
Transcript written in thesis.alg.
Rule 'cusdep acn acr thesis': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'thesis.acn'
------------
Run number 4 of rule 'cusdep acn acr thesis'
------------
Latexmk: applying rule 'cusdep acn acr thesis'...
For rule 'cusdep acn acr thesis', running '&do_cusdep( makeacn2acr )' ...
This is makeindex, version 2.15 [TeX Live 2015] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning style file ./thesis.ist.............................done (29 attributes redefined, 0 ignored).
Scanning input file thesis.acn...done (0 entries accepted, 0 rejected).
Nothing written in thesis.acr.
Transcript written in thesis.alg.
Rule 'pdflatex': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'thesis.acr'
      'thesis.aux'
      'thesis.toc'
Latexmk: Maximum runs of pdflatex reached without getting stable files
Latexmk: Did not finish processing file 'thesis.tex':
   'pdflatex' needed too many passes
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs of latex/pdflatex.
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
```

I am sure that glossaries are the problem because the `thesis.acr' file keeps updating with every run, also if I comment out the commands that prints the glossaries it manages to compile just fine. The weird thing is if I trash the aux files it manages to compile just fine as well.

This is what my `latexmkrcedit' file looks like, I see that it does acknowledge problems with the glossaries but I have no idea what to do about it:

```
# Don't edit this file IF it is named latexmkrcDONTedit directly since
#   TeXShop may replace it on update.
# If you wish to edit or add to this file, copy it to ~/Library/TeXShop/bin
#   and rename it latexmkrcedit if that file doesn't already exist.

# Edit this File to add/change dependencies and rules
# The following is used by ALL the latexmk engine files

# change the empty string ,'', to '--shell-escape' to add the shell-escape default
$TSUserCompileOptions = '';
#$TSUserCompileOptions = '--shell-escape';

# turn recorder option off (no .fls file generated)
#$recorder=0;

# turn off duplicated missing references
$silence_logfile_warnings = 1;

# Custom dependency for glossary/glossaries package
# if you make custom glossaries you may have to add items to the @cus_dep_list and corresponding sub-routines
add_cus_dep('glo', 'gls', 0, 'makeglo2gls');
        sub makeglo2gls {
                system("makeindex -s '$_[0]'.ist -t '$_[0]'.glg -o '$_[0]'.gls '$_[0]'.glo");
        }
# The glossaries package, with the [acronym] option, produces a .acn file when processed with (xe/pdf)latex and
# then makeindex to process the .acn into .acr and finally runs of (xe/pdf)latex to read in the .acr file. Unfortunately
# the glossary package does just the reverse; i.e. (xe/pdf)latex processing produces a .acr files and makeindex then
# is used to convert the .acr file to a .acn file which is then ... . This dependency assumes the glossaries package.
add_cus_dep('acn', 'acr', 0, 'makeacn2acr');
        sub makeacn2acr {
                system("makeindex -s '$_[0]'.ist -t '$_[0]'.alg -o '$_[0]'.acr '$_[0]'.acn");
        }
# for glossary package (Sigh...) --- they can co-exist!     
add_cus_dep('acr', 'acn', 0, 'makeacr2acn');
        sub makeacr2acn {
                system("makeindex -s '$_[0]'.ist -t '$_[0]'.alg -o '$_[0]'.acn '$_[0]'.acr");
        }
# example of an added custom glossary type that is used in some of the glossary/glossaries example files:
# this is for the new glossary type command \newglossary[nlg]{notation}{not}{ntn}{Notation} from the glossaries package
# NOTE: the glossary package uses a very different command: the <in-ext> and <out-ext>
# are reversed in the calling sequence :-(
add_cus_dep('ntn', 'not', 0, 'makentn2not');
        sub makentn2not {
                system("makeindex -s '$_[0]'.ist -t '$_[0]'.nlg -o '$_[0]'.not '$_[0]'.ntn");
        }
# for the   glossary package (Sigh...) --- they can co-exist!
add_cus_dep('not', 'ntn', 0, 'makenot2ntn');
        sub makenot2ntn {
                system("makeindex -s '$_[0]'.ist -t '$_[0]'.nlg -o '$_[0]'.ntn '$_[0]'.not");
        }

# dependencies for custom indexes using the index package
# examples for sample.tex for index package:
 add_cus_dep('adx', 'and', 0, 'makeadx2and');
        sub makeadx2and {
                system("makeindex -o '$_[0]'.and '$_[0]'.adx");
        }
 add_cus_dep('ndx', 'nnd', 0, 'makendx2nnd');
        sub makendx2nnd {
                system("makeindex -o '$_[0]'.nnd '$_[0]'.ndx");
        }
 add_cus_dep('ldx', 'lnd', 0, 'makeldx2lnd');
     sub makeldx2lnd {
             system("makeindex -o '$_[0]'.lnd '$_[0]'.ldx");
     }

# Custom dependency and function for nomencl package
add_cus_dep('nlo', 'nls', 0, 'makenlo2nls');
        sub makenlo2nls {
                system("makeindex -s nomencl.ist -o '$_[0]'.nls '$_[0]'.nlo");
        }
```

I would really appreciate the help, it's frustrating when you can't concentrate on the content because of random problems.
Thanks.

Comment: The problem may have something to do with the message `Scanning input file thesis.acr...done (0 entries accepted, 72 rejected)`. The call to `makeindex` has failed for some reason and isn't creating the `thesis.acn` file. Check the log file `thesis.alg` for error messages.

Comment: Hi, I had thought about that but the file gets rewritten with the following run without errors, any idea how to read it before it changes?

Comment: Since the `glossary` package is obsolete, I recommend commenting out the `makeacr2acn` dependency code. It's my fault for mixing up the file extensions when I replaced the `glossary` package with the `glossaries` package, but since `glossary` was deprecated years ago there doesn't seem any point in trying to support it in `latexmk`. The `makeglossaries` script makes it much easier by reading the `.aux` file to determine the files used by `glossaries`, but I don't know how to incorporate that into `latexmk` (which is one of the reasons why I prefer `arara` to `latexmk`)

Comment: Thanks, commenting out that part seems to work. I didn't know about arara, I am going to give it a try

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is partly my fault for muddling the file extensions when I replaced [`glossary`](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossary) with [`glossaries`](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries). The *input* file from LaTeX's point of view is the *output* file from the indexing application's point of view, and the *output* file from LaTeX's point of view is the *input* file from the indexing application's point of view. I confused my ins and outs because I was looking at it from the wrong point of view.

If you're using `glossaries` the file dependency chain is "if there's a `.glo` file, run `makeindex` to create the `.gls` file". This means you need

```
add_cus_dep('glo', 'gls', 0, 'makeglo2gls');
sub makeglo2gls {
  system("makeindex -s '$_[0]'.ist -t '$_[0]'.glg -o '$_[0]'.gls '$_[0]'.glo");
}
```

in your `latexmkrcedit` file.

The reverse process `makegls2glo` works for the old `glossary` package. Problems ensue if you have both `makeglo2gls` and `makegls2glo`. If you're using `glossaries`, you need to remove the `makegls2glo` code from the `latexmkrcedit` file. This is the cause of your particular issue.

However, there's more of a problem here, not just for `latexmk` but for other build processes, where the assumption is that you have to run

```
makeindex -s basename -t basename.glg -o basename.gls basename.glo
```

where the LaTeX file is called `basename.tex`. This includes post-processor profiles and user-created batch files.

The `glossaries` package's flexibility allows it to be used for a wide variety of documents, but this flexibility inhibits a simple file-dependency build.

Let's consider a simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{sample}{name={sample},
 description={an example}}

\begin{document}
\gls{sample}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

This fits in with the basic file-dependency model. If the file is called `test.tex`, then you need to run:

```
makeindex -s test.ist -t test.glg -o test.gls test.glo
```

Now let's suppose we have a minor modification:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\setStyleFile{mygloss}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{sample}{name={sample},
 description={an example}}

\begin{document}
\gls{sample}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Now the call to `makeindex` is:

```
makeindex -s mygloss.ist -t test.glg -o test.gls test.glo
```

which doesn't fit the basic model.

Now let's suppose we have:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nomain]{glossaries}

\newglossary[glg]{main}{glo}{gls}{Glossary}%

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{sample}{name={sample},
 description={an example}}

\begin{document}
\gls{sample}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

This flips the file extensions back to the way they were with the original `glossary` package, so now the call to `makeindex` is:

```
makeindex -s test.ist -t test.glg -o test.glo test.gls
```

Now let's suppose we have:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nomain]{glossaries}

\newglossary*{unit}{Units}
\newglossary*{sym}{Symbols}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{mm}{type={unit},
 name={millimetre},
 description={length unit}}

\newglossaryentry{alpha}{type={sym},
 name={\ensuremath{\alpha}},
 sort={alpha},
 description={alpha}}

\begin{document}
\gls{mm}, \gls{alpha}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

This requires:

```
makeindex -s test.ist -t test.unit-glg -o test.unit-gls test.unit-glo
makeindex -s test.ist -t test.sym-glg -o test.sym-gls test.sym-glo
```

The [`glossary-lipsum-examples.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/samples/glossary-lipsum-examples.tex) sample file that comes with the `glossaries` package has ten glossaries. Each one needs a separate `makeindex` call.

Perhaps I want to switch from `makeindex`'s default word order to letter order for a particular document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[order=letter]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{seal}{name={seal},
 description={aquatic mammal}}

\newglossaryentry{sealion}{name={sealion},
 description={a type of \gls{seal} with ears}}

\begin{document}
\gls{seal}, \gls{sealion}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

This needs the `-l` switch:

```
makeindex -l -s test.ist -t test.glg -o test.gls test.glo
```

but only for that document.

Perhaps I want to use `xindy` instead of `makeindex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[order=letter,xindy]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{seal}{name={seal},
 description={aquatic mammal}}

\newglossaryentry{sealion}{name={sealion},
 description={a type of \gls{seal} with ears}}

\begin{document}
\gls{seal}, \gls{sealion}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

This now needs:

```
xindy -M ord/letorder -L english -I xindy -M test -t test.glg -o test.gls test.glo
```

So these hard-coded rules used by testing the existence of common file extensions in `latexmk` or simple hard-coded invocations of `makeindex` in post-processors can't cope with the wide variety of options that may be used with `glossaries`.

This is why `glossaries` provides the `makeglossaries` Perl script. This parses the `.aux` file to determine what to do.

For that last example, the `.aux` file includes the lines:

```
\@xdylanguage{main}{british}
\@gls@codepage{main}{}
\@newglossary{main}{glg}{gls}{glo}
\@istfilename{test.xdy}
\@glsorder{letter}
```

This provides `makeglossaries` with all the information it needs, so if I do

```
makeglossaries test
```

it knows to use `xindy` instead of `makeindex` (from the file extension in `\@istfilename`), it knows that letter order is required (`\@glsorder`), it knows the input/output/transcript file extensions (from `\@newglossary`). If `xindy` is required, it also knows what language is in use for each glossary (from `\@xdylanguage`) and the input encoding, if the `inputenc` package has been used (from `\@gls@codepage`, empty in this case as the document doesn't load `inputenc`).

There's a light-weight Lua alternative to `makeglossaries` which also parses the `.aux` file, but it's more restrictive than `makeglossaries`. For example, `makeglossaries` knows that `babel`'s `british` language option needs to be passed to `xindy` with the `-L english` switch. The Lua version doesn't have these language mappings, so if you use `makeglossaries-lite.lua`, you need:

```
\usepackage[order=letter,xindy={language=english,codepage=utf8}]{glossaries}
```

Here's another example where `makeglossaries` works better than a direct call to `makeindex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{seal}{name={seal},
 description={aquatic mammal}}

\newglossaryentry{sealion}{name={sealion},
 description={a type of \gls{seal} with ears}}

\begin{document}
\gls[format=textbf]{seal}, \gls{sealion} and \gls{seal} again.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

If I explicitly do:

```
makeindex -s test.ist -t test.glg -o test.gls test.glo
```

I get a warning from `makeindex`:

```
## Warning (input = test.glo, line = 1; output = test.gls, line = 5):
   -- Conflicting entries: multiple encaps for the same page under same key.
```

The location list for the `seal` entry has page 1 repeated, first in the normal font and then in bold:

**seal** aquatic mammal. 1, **1**

This is something that `makeglossaries` checks for and tries to fix, so if I do

```
makeglossaries test
```

instead, the messages include the following:

```
Multiple encaps detected. Attempting to remedy.
```

The resulting `test.pdf` file now only has the bold page 1 in the location list for the `seal` entry. (The Lua version `makeglossaries-lite.lua` doesn't do this.) This doesn't occur with `xindy` as `xindy` will discard the `textbf` location without comment.

Some of the `xindy` messages can be a bit cryptic, but `makeglossaries` checks for them and tries to supply a more informative error message. Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{P}{
 name={\P},
 description={paragraph symbol}}

\begin{document}
\gls{P}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

This produces the following error message from `xindy`:

```
WARNING: Would replace complete index key by empty string,
         ignoring
         #<ordrule-regexp: '\\[a-zA-Z@]+ *' => '' :again NIL :only-at-start NIL>
```

What does this mean? If I use `makeglossaries`, I get a more informative message:

```
Sort key required for entries only containing command names
Attempting to determine which entries have problem sort keys
Parsing 'test.glo'
1 problematic entry found:

Label: 'P'. Sort value : '\\P '
(Try adding sort={P} to the definition.)
```

The problem here is that the `P` entry needs the sort key, so I need to correct my LaTeX code:

```
\newglossaryentry{P}{
 name={\P},
 sort=P,
 description={paragraph symbol}}
```

This is why I think that post-processor profiles and other build tools should really use `makeglossaries` rather than trying to call `makeindex` explicitly.

Personally I prefer to use [`arara`](http://ctan.org/pkg/arara) even though I'm in the habit of using `make` as a general compile tool, as this allows me to customise the build process on a per-document basis, so I can just do:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{seal}{name={seal},
 description={aquatic mammal}}

\newglossaryentry{sealion}{name={sealion},
 description={a type of \gls{seal} with ears}}

\begin{document}
\gls[format=textbf]{seal}, \gls{sealion} and \gls{seal} again.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

or with version 4.0:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeglossaries if found("aux", "@istfilename")
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{seal}{name={seal},
 description={aquatic mammal}}

\newglossaryentry{sealion}{name={sealion},
 description={a type of \gls{seal} with ears}}

\begin{document}
\gls[format=textbf]{seal}, \gls{sealion} and \gls{seal} again.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

which is more convenient if I can't decide on `\makeglossaries` or `\makenoidxglossaries`.

Comment: I already had solved the problem with your previous suggestions and I really appreciate the time you invested putting together a detailed explanation with lots of examples, I now properly understand what's going on. Thanks again.

Comment: @PaoloIzzo That's okay. :-)