# Glossaries are not working with latexmk

Tags: glossaries, latexmk

I have my glossaries in glossary.tex

I always input them to the main.tex then /makeglossaries and then /printglossaries

I am using atom IDE on windows.
When I run the latex compilation, I cannot see glossaries in the resulting pdf file even when I used them.

Here is the code of the main file:

```
\documentclass[11pt,
              a4paper,
              index=totoc,
              headsepline,
              footsepline,
              BCOR=12mm,
              DIV=13]{scrbook}

\input{components/info}

\input{components/settings}

\input{components/commands}

\input{components/glossary}

\makeglossary

\begin{document}

 \frontmatter

 \input{components/cover}

 \clearemptydoublepage

 \input{components/titlepage}

 \input{components/disclaimer}

 \input{components/acknowledgements}

 \input{components/quote}

 \input{components/abstract}

 \tableofcontents

 \mainmatter

 \input{components/text}

 \clearemptydoublepage

 \printglossaries

 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
 \listoffigures

 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
 \listoftables

 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
 \bibliography{bibliography/literature}

\end{document}
```

Do you have any clues what can fix the problem?

Comment: [Welcome to tex.se !](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) The first error I see is `Missing input file: 'main.gls'`. How  did you define your glossaries ? Could you put a MWE ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Possibly related: [latexmk reaches maximum runs when including new glossaries entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/306995).

Comment: Actually, The problem was with .bib file. When I fixed it, everything is ok. Although, it does not print glossaries even when I used the terms in the text.

Comment: @mark Did you include a `\printglossaries`-like command in your code?

Comment: @Troy yes. The thing is that I do not get this error any more but the glossaries are still not printed

Comment: @mark Well, we can't help much if you don't show us your code. We can only guess..

Comment: @Troy I have updated the question

Comment: @mark The code you uploaded is not of much use. Everything is hidden behind `\input` files which we have no access to. Make it into a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).. Meanwhile, is your `latexmk` configured to run `makeglossaries`? See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1226/117534 (disclaimer: i don't use latexmk myself..)

Comment: @Troy thanks for the link to another similar question but I have seen it before and it is not much of use because I am using windows. Ok will try to give you more details about the project

Comment: Try with [`mwe-gls.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/samples/mwe-gls.tex), which is a MWE supplied with the `glossaries` package. Do you get a glossary with that? If not, try with `\usepackage[automake]{glossaries}`.